# SQL get duplicate records for all the users

Tags: sql

I have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE subject 
(
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  name varchar(20)   
);

INSERT INTO subject
  (name)
VALUES
  ('subject 1'),('subject 2'), ('subject 3');

CREATE TABLE course 
(
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  name varchar(20),
  subject_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject(id)
);

INSERT INTO course
  (subject_id, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'course 1'),(1, 'course 2'), (2, 'course 3'), (3, 'course 4');

CREATE TABLE user 
(
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  name varchar(20),
  course_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course(id)
);

INSERT INTO user
  (course_id, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'User 1'),(1, 'User 1'), (2, 'User 3'), (3, 'User 4');
```

I want to get a list of users who belong to the course which belongs to the same subject.

I ran this query to get the list

```
select u.name as user_name, s.name as subject_name from user u
inner join course c on u.course_id = c.id
inner join subject s on c.subject_id = s.id;
```

And this is the output

```
USER_NAME   SUBJECT_NAME
User 1           subject 1
User 1           subject 1
User 3           subject 1
User 4           subject 2
```

Expected output

```
USER_NAME   SUBJECT_NAME
User 1           subject 1
User 1           subject 1
```

how to I select only user 1 who has a course that belongs to the same subject ??

[fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d7b1/11/0)

Comment: Are you looking a distinct + group by?

Comment: distinct would fetch me the unique records, I need to display the duplicate records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the List of users who have got more than 1 course enrolled, use below query in the fiddle:

```
select u.name as user_name, s.name as subject_name from user u
inner join course c on u.course_id = c.id
inner join subject s on c.subject_id = s.id
having count(1) > 1;
```

To Get only distinct users and courses, use below query :

```
select distinct u.name as user_name, s.name as subject_name from user u
inner join course c on u.course_id = c.id
inner join subject s on c.subject_id = s.id;
```

**EDIT:** I assume you need the number of distinct users who have taken the subject for which you can use below query:

```
select  s.name as subject_name, count(distinct(u.name)) as no_of_users from user u
inner join course c on u.course_id = c.id
inner join subject s on c.subject_id = s.id
group by s.name;
```

By using just `count(u.name) as no_of_users` You would get the actual count rather than distinct count.

**EDIT AGAIN**

To get the required output, the below query works!

```
select tab_a.user_name, tab_a.subject_name from
(
   select u.name as user_name, s.name as subject_name from user u
   inner join course c on u.course_id = c.id
   inner join subject s on c.subject_id = s.id  
)tab_a
inner join
(
   select u.name as user_name, s.name as subject_name, count(1) reccount from user u
   inner join course c on u.course_id = c.id
   inner join subject s on c.subject_id = s.id
   group by u.name, s.name
) tab_b
on tab_a.user_name = tab_b.user_name
where tab_b.reccount >1
```

Comment: not enrolled in more than 1 course, I need the list of students who have enrolled to the courses which belong to the same subject.

Comment: the output should be like list of users who have subscribed to a course whihc belongs to the same subject.

Comment: user|subject id
xx | 1
xx | 1
xxx | 2
xxx | 2

Comment: @Ajey: Please update your question with the expected answer! I am sorry am not able to understand what you want.

Comment: In your question, you have pasted "This is the output right?" Same way, just post this is the expected output so that Viewers can have better clarity!

Comment: Nisha, please check , I have mentioned the expected output

Comment: @Ajey: Please check edit. This works! Please modify/optimize query as required.